# Get closure variables for nested lambdas

Tags: python

I'd like to get the closure variables inside as a nested lambda:

```py
g_cut_value = 30

def test_python_capture():
    import inspect

    print("simple global: " + str(inspect.getclosurevars(lambda e: g_cut_value).globals))
    print("nested global: " + str(inspect.getclosurevars(lambda e: (lambda x: g_cut_value)(e)).globals))
```

The output from this is:

```sh
simple global: {'g_cut_value': 30}
nested global: {}
```

This is expected in the sense that I'm getting the closure over the outer function. I'd like to go deeper, however, and get the closure over inner functions as well. I'd like to do it without executing any of the lambda code.

What I'm Trying To Do: In my main code base I use `getsource` to fetch the source code for the lambda function and translate it to a python `ast`. I then convert the `ast` to another language and execute it: so the python code is never directly executed. I'd like to allow for the user to specify captured variables to pass in.

Given this context, I could re-write the [`getclosurevars`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/562c13f5734d406b2283cfca673611f4b496fdc7/Lib/inspect.py#L1588) source to run over the `ast`, but I'm hoping there is another approved/pythonic way to do this that doesn't require working at that low a level.

Comment: "however, and get the closure over inner functions as well. I'd like to do it without executing any of the lambda code." well, see, the inner function **doesn't exist** unless the outer lambda is executed, only a compiled code-object could exist, which you can retreive from the outer lambda in `(lambda : ...).__code__.co_consts` and then introspect *that* code object and the appropriate `.co_*` attributes

Comment: Oh! But `co_consts` does contain the nested lambda - so this is just a matter of traversing the code objects? I'm not sure what you by "could exist" - are there circumstances under which it doesn't exist?

Comment: I meant " would exist"

Comment: Ok - thanks. That makes some sense. Right now I'm just using the global variable context, and the result from the `inspect` module for the outer. Since these `lambda` functions do not have other statements in them, they can't have local variables, so this works for now. But it is specific to my app, not to python in general. Given that, if you want to write your comment up as an answer, I'll mark it as correct.